# Excel VBA math type formula with variable operator doesn't work on decimal numbers

Tags: vba, excel, operators

I have a small script designed to perform simple math operations where the operator is defined as a variable. The only problem is that it only works on integers, not decimal numbers. Anyone have an idea why?
I've tried to separate the operator and the number into two variables, but the problem persists.

```
Sub CellMath2()
Call CreateSheetBackup
Dim rng As Range
Dim expression As Variant
expression = InputBox("Enter operator (* / + - ^) and number (e.g. ""*1000"").", "Operator and number")
If StrPtr(expression) = 0 Then Exit Sub
For Each rng In Selection
If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(rng) Then
    rng.Value = "=" & rng & expression
    rng.Value = rng.Value
Else
End If
Next rng
End Sub
```

Comment: It works for me. What is your decimal separator? Comma or point?

Comment: Comma, but I did try to change system settings to point decimal, and I still got the error ... Weird. Possibly some arcane language setting problem?

Comment: What do you put in the inputbox? could you give an example? VBA always uses the US English formats, reardless of your system settings. So in the inputbox, one will always have to insert number with a decimal point, not a comma.

Comment: I've always used whole numbers while testing, e.g. "*1000". But thanks for the info; that gives me another problem to solve, ;).

Comment: And I see I get the same error if I use a decimal comma in the input box on an integer. So I guess the error is related to that.

Comment: Yeah, I'm testing it. Funny error. VBA understands 1,5, Excel understands 1,5, but when VBA is passing a value to Excel, it has to be 1.5. Format() doesn't work, so I'm afraid you will have to do some disgusting text replacements... Bleh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`Evaluate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-evaluate-method-excel) method.

Usage as such:

```
For Each rng In Selection
    If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(rng) Then
        rng.Value = Evaluate(Replace(rng & expression, ",", "."))
    End If
Next rng
```

`Evaluate` accepts the same style of operators as a formula does, at least largely, so if you have `A1` with value of `10` and `expression="+10"`, then `Evaluate(Range("A1") & expression` would give you `20`.

`Replace(rng, ",", ".")` to convert from European decimals to the US-standard (which VBA uses).

Comment: It works for integers, but when I use it on decimal numbers, I get a "#VALUE" error, for some reason.

Comment: Most likely because you're not using EN-US localization. Updated code to convert it. Note that you'll either need to add the same `Replace` to your `InputBox` or instruct your users to enter decimal values with `.` instead of `,`

Comment: On closer inspection, [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48296580/4604845) in this thread already solved that problem...

Comment: At any rate, the newest update now corrects all instances of the decimal separator

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat! I had tried to add `If Application.DecimalSeparator = "," Then rng = Replace(rng, ",", ".")`, but that didn't work. Your updated code did the trick, though.

Answer (score 1):

try to use following line after inputbox:

```
If Application.ThousandsSeparator = " " Then expression = Replace(expression, " ", "")
If Application.DecimalSeparator = "," Then expression = Replace(expression, ",", ".")
```

Comment: I'd do the replacement on the output, as decimal and thousand separators might appear in the cells as well. And the error occurs when VBA tries to write the value to the Excel cell. Also, space as a thousand separator doesn't cause any problems, but . (dot) does, so I'd change that instead.

Comment: This does work for the problem of using comma in the inputbox, Thanks. But I still have the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can separate the operator and number and use a case select statement, but then I have to include all possible operators and limit the functionality to the operators I include.

This works, with decimal comma in the inputbox and the cell:

```
Sub CellMath()
Dim rng As Range
Dim c As Variant, operator As Variant
operator = InputBox("Enter operator (* / + - ^ or e).", "Operator")
If StrPtr(operator) = 0 Then Exit Sub
c = InputBox("Enter number.", "Number")
If StrPtr(c) = 0 Then Exit Sub
For Each rng In Selection
If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(rng) Then
Select Case operator
    Case "*"
    rng.Value = rng * c
    Case "/"
    rng.Value = rng / c
    Case "+"
    rng.Value = rng + c
    Case "-"
    rng.Value = rng - c
    Case "^"
    rng.Value = rng ^ c
    Case "e"
    rng.Value = rng * 10 ^ c
End Select
Else
End If
Next rng
End Sub
```

Any interesting operators I've forgotten here?